# regex to convert find instances a single \

Tags: java, regex

I am looking to replace `\n` with `\\n` but so far my regex attempts are not working (Really it is any \ by itself, \n just happens to be the use case I have in the data).

What I need is something along the lines of:

```
any-non-\ followed by \ followed by any-non-\
```

Ultimately I'll be passing the regex to java.lang.String.replaceAll so a regex formatted for that would be great, but I can probably translate another style regex into what I need.

For example I after this program to print out "true"...

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final String original;
        final String altered;
        final String expected;

        original = "hello\nworld";
        expected = "hello\\nworld";
        altered  = original.replaceAll("([^\\\\])\\\\([^\\\\])", "$1\\\\$2");
        System.out.println(altered.equals(expected));
   }
}
```

using this does work:

```
    altered  = original.replaceAll("\\n", "\\\\n");
```

Comment: you need to escape the backslash char, so you need to use two of them eg `\\\`

Comment: "I am looking to replace \n with \n"

How zen of you...;)

Your question is a little hard to understand. Do you have an example string and can you also give an example of the expected result?

Comment: Sarfraz: I've tried all the ways I can think of... thing seems to have worked.

Comment: original does not contain \, you need to escape the backslash characters in original and expected too.

Comment: Yeah, there's a newline character but no backslashes.

Comment: the data is coming from a JSON response... it has a \n (as far as I can tell it is supposed to be \\n in JSON but the server isn't doing the escaping...)

Answer (score 2):

The string should be

```
"[^\\\\]\\\\[^\\\\]"
```

You have to *quadruple* backslashes in a String constant that's meant for a regex; if you only doubled them, they would be escaped for the String but not for the regex.

So the actual code would be

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("([^\\\\])\\\\([^\\\\])", "$1\\\\$2");
```

<s>Note that in the replacement, a quadruple backslash is now interpreted as two backslashes rather than one, since the regex engine is not parsing it.</s> **Edit:** Actually, the regex engine does parse it since it has to check for the backreferences.

**Edit:** The above was assuming that there was a literal `\n` in the input string, which is represented in a string literal as `"\\n"`. Since it apparently has a newline instead (represented as `"\n"`), the correct substitution would be

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("\\n", "\\\\n");
```

This must be repeated for any other special characters (`\t`, `\r`, `\0`, `\\`, etc.). <s>As above, the replacement string looks exactly like the regex string but isn't.</s>

Comment: didn't do it... Ive updated the question with a simple bit of code

Comment: yes, but I don't want to just have it work for \n as there could be \\(anything) and I want that to be \\\(anything).  The only example I have, so far, in the data is t \n but I'd rather not limit the code to \n.

Comment: @TofuBeer: My point is, those characters do not actually have a backslash--the backslashes are only in the Java representation. They have nothing else in common. For example, `\n` is equivalent to `\u000A` and `\t` is equivalent to `\u0009` (the complete list is at http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.6).

Comment: well the issue is a bit different though too... the \ can appear anywhere in the JSON data not just the Java specific ones.  Looking further I did verify that \ in JSON is to be encoded as \\.  For now I;ll just handle them as they come up and work with the data provider to properly encode the JSON objects.

Comment: @TofuBeer: I guess I still don't understand the requirements, then. Are there backslashes or are there not?

Comment: Here is an example error JSON string (comes from an HTTP server): "highlight":"Shaun White Captures Olympic Gold with Double McTwist 1260:King of the mountain.\nIn a stunning display of twists... http://bit.ly/9uGdVo".  The \n is supposed to be \\n bu the server sends the wrong thing.  So on my end I want to replace all of the \n with \\n before I process it.

Comment: @TofuBeer: How are you viewing the contents of the string? Are you printing it out or using a debugger?

Comment: Hmmm... trying to get a more realistic reproducible case isn't working out.  The \n came from the JSON file saved to disk.  At this point I'm just going to punt, go with what I have, and try and get the data source fixed since that is the real problem.  I'd rather not have to massage the data at all.

Answer (score 1):

So whenever there is 1 backslash, you want 2, but if there is 2, 3 or 4... in a row, leave them alone?

you want to replace

```
(?<=[^\\])\\(?!\\+)([^\\])
```

with

```
\\$1
```

That changes the string

```
hello\nworld and hello\\nworld and hello\\\nworld
```

into

```
hello\\nworld and hello\\nworld and hello\\\nworld
```

Comment: Yes, 1 back slash becomes 2, 2 ore more stays the same.  I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @Tofu, I'm no Java guy, but I believe you will need to escape the backslashes in the strings you use for creating your regex.  As, unlike c#, Java doesn't have verbatim strings (http://www.javacamp.org/javavscsharp/string.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you need it for, but you could have a look at [`StringEscapeUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) from [Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/). They have plenty of methods doing things like that, and if you don't find exactly what you're searching for, you could have a look at the source to find inspiration :)

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with using `altered = original.replaceAll("\\n", "\\\\n");` ? That's exactly what i would have done.